altimetry/altitude difference between Adriatic and Baltic Sea
How can someone find the level difference between Adriatic and Baltic Sea in order to combare/calibrate two different stations in Hungary, one measuring in mBf (meaning meters above Baltic Sea) and the other one in mAf (meaning meters above Adriatic Sea)? I understand that -taking out any tidal effects- the two Seas should be at the same level, which should be 0. Now, looking at some altimetry data from DAHITI for one river close to the Adriatic Sea (Corno, River; 45.7924 °N, 13.232 °E) and one close to Baltic Sea (Parseta, River; 54.155 °N, 15.5758 °E), i get for the former -0.33 m and for the latter 0.52 m? Is it reasonable to have a difference between the two Seas?

The Wikipedia page on metres_above_the_adriatic gives various relative references to Austria, which uses an Adriatic gauge, this suggests that there is a difference of around 65 cms, with the Baltic being higher than the Adriatic.  Lots of factors, such as tides, local gravitational pull, temperature and salinity, will all influence relative sea levels
